# Javascript onmouseover stop menu

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, dom-events

I have this small menu. All I want is to open it with one click and then to close it with another click outside the html element.

I figured out only how to open it with a click but don't know how to close it:

- HTML portion:

```html
<div id="sign"onclick="setVisibility()">
  login
  <div id="user"></div>
  <br>
  <p id="userl">Streamer1228</p><br>
  <div id="userll"  >PREMIUM USER</p><br>
  <button id="logout"  >Logout</button>
</div>
```

- JavaScript code:

```js
function setVisibility() {
  document.getElementById("sign").style.height="350px";
}
```

Comment: you can add event listener to document click event, and hide you menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is using an if condition:

```
function setVisibility() {
if (document.getElementById("sign").style.height=="350px"){
document.getElementById("sign").style.height="0px";} else {
document.getElementById("sign").style.height="350px";} 
}
```

Comment: That's exactly i was asking!

Answer (score 0):

You can register an `onclick` event fot the whole `document` and check whether the element clicked is your *sign* `div` or not and proceed on that basis. You may also need and element that once clicked, you will show your *sign* block because when the *sign* element is hidden, you won't be able to capture events on it. Here goes a sample *thanks to [@Josh response on that post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1455186/2106516)*:

```js
document.onclick = function(evt) {
  if(clickedOnElement('showSign', evt)) {
    var signElmt = document.getElementById("sign");
      if (signElmt.style.display == 'none') {
        signElmt.style.display = 'block';
        signElmt.style.visibility = 'visible';
      }
  } else {
    if (!clickedOnElement('sign', evt)) {
      var signElmt = document.getElementById("sign");
      signElmt.style.display = 'none';
      signElmt.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
  }
}

function clickedOnElement(element, event) {
  var clickedElement = getEventTarget(event);      
  if(clickedElement.id == element)
    return true;
  return false;
}

function getEventTarget(evt) {
  var targ = (evt.target) ? evt.target : evt.srcElement;
  if(targ && targ.nodeType == 3)
      targ = targ.parentNode;
  return targ;
}
```

### *[DEMO on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wvbjjqgv/1/)*

<sup>Note that this code may need some enhancements.</sup>

Answer (score -1):

If you okay with jquery, simply use

```
function setVisibility() {
  $('#sign').slideToggle('slow');
}
```

In Javascript Toggle

```
 var toggleSign = document.getElementById("sign");  
 toggleSign.style.display == "block" ? toggleSign.style.display = "none" :toggleSign.style.display = "block";
```